# Greatest prime factor of n and n+1

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

For a positive integer $n$ we denote its largest prime factor by $\operatorname{gpf}(n)$. Let's call a pair of distinct primes $(p,q)$ $\textbf{nice}$ if there are no natural numbers $n$ such that $\operatorname{gpf}(n)=p, \operatorname{gpf}(n+1)=q$ or $\operatorname{gpf}(n)=q, \operatorname{gpf}(n+1)=p$. For example, $(2,23)$ is nice.

Are there nice pairs $(p,q)$ with $p,q>100$?

Comment: Likely yes. One place to look is Stoermer's theorem on consecutive smooth integers. If you set a bound N (so gpf of such smooth integers is at most N), there will be finitely many consecutive pairs of such smooth integers, so I believe the claim that (2,19) is nice.  I don't know, but I suspect a theorem like for every prime p there are infinitely many q with (p,q) is approachable from Stoermers theorem.  Gerhard "Too Tired To Stroke Now" Paseman, 2019.05.30.

Comment: In fact, such a claim might be provable from an analysis of A,B, with Ap +Bq=1. I can see such arithmetic progressions avoiding pairs of smooth numbers.  Gerhard "We'll Trace One Warm Line..." Paseman, 2019.05.30.

Comment: @DmitryKrachun Actually, with $n = 512$, note that $512 = 2^9$, so $\text{gpf}(512) = 2$, and $513 = 3^3 \times 19$, so $\text{gpf}(513) = 19$. This shows by your definition that $(2,19)$ is *not* nice.

Comment: @JohnOmielan You showed that $(19,2)$ is not nice, not $(2,19)$

Comment: @AsymptotiacK The question says "... distinct primes $(p,q)$ $\textbf{nice}$ if there are no natural numbers $n$ such that $\operatorname{gpf}(n)=p, \operatorname{gpf}(n+1)=q$ or $\operatorname{gpf}(n)=q, \operatorname{gpf}(n+1)=p$." The condition is of the form $A \text{ or } B$, where I assume it's the standard inclusive English "or", so it holds if either *or* both $A$ & $B$ are true. In this particular case, $p = 2$, $q = 19$ & $n = 512$, with condition $A$ holding, & $B$ for $(19,2)$. Thus, as being **nice** requires **no** natural numbers $n$, both $(2,19)$ & $(19,2)$ are *not* **nice**.

Comment: @DmitryKrachun Both $(2,23)$ and $(23,2)$ are **nice** (actually, as you know, if $(p,q)$ is nice, then so is $(q.p)$) since $2^{11} - 1 = 23 \times 89$ and $23$ doesn't divide any $2^n \pm 1$ for an $n \lt 11$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Oops, I misread the question

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, thanks, I edited the question. It's actually relatively easy to show that $(2, p)$ is nice for infinitely many primes $p$.

Comment: @AsymptotiacK No worries. I have spent so much time programming where the OR operator is inclusive that I forgot with English, although "or" is somewhat ambiguous, it's usually used in an exclusive sense. However, this is a moot point here as the two conditions can never be simultaneously true.

Comment: @DmitryKrachun You're welcome. I haven't spent very much time thinking about or checking on your problem, but it seems the difficulty & complexity of finding & proving pairs of primes are nice is large, even where the smaller prime is a very small odd prime, and grows very quickly for larger primes. Do you know of any $p$ where $(3,p)$ is nice, much less where $(5,p), (7,p), \ldots$ are nice?

Comment: @JohnOmielan I don't know any nice pair with $p,q>2$...

Comment: @DmitryKrachun Do you have any particular reason to believe there are any nice pair at all with $p,q \gt 2$? Even just for $p$ or $q$ being $3$, there are already so relatively many possible values for $n$ or $n+1$ being of the form $3^i 2^j$ where $i \ge 1$ and $j \ge 0$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan So here is an argument why I believe there are in fact nice pairs with $p,q>100$. Take $p=101$ and let $S$ be the set of $101-$smooth numbers . There are around $\log^A{x}$ of such numbers up to $x$ for constant $A$. For each $x\in S$ number $x\pm 1$ is kind of a random number so it has probability $x^{-1/(2A)+o(1)}$ to be $\log^{2A}{x}$-smooth. Since $\sum_{x\in S}x^{-1/(2A)}<\infty$ there are only finitely many numbers $x\in S$ for which $x+1$ or $x-1$ is $\log^{2A}{x}$-smooth. From that, it is easy to see that most primes are not appearing as $\operatorname{gpf}(x\pm 1)$.

Comment: @DmitryKrachun Thanks for showing your approach. I feel a bit silly. For a given prime $p$ & $x$, the density of integers $n$ for which $\operatorname{gpf}(n) = p$ can be fairly large when $\log_p{x}$ is quite small, but the density among larger $n$ as $x$ increases becomes very small. I now don't doubt the existence for any given $p$ of nice pairs $(p,q)$ (e.g., [Størmer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem) Gerhard's comment mentioned). The challenge is determining & proving any given pair when the $p,q$ become larger, such as Gerhard's answer below indicates.

Answer (score 9):

So running a simple sieve algorithm allows for recording  pairs which are not nice, and there are many of them below 9 million. I get that the complement includes (2,q) for q=23,29,37,47, and more, (3,q)  for q=89,103,113,131,137 and more, (5,q) for q=307,503,509,613,619 and some more, (7,q) for q=967,971,1031,1039,1049 and some more, (11,q) for q=2381,2543,2551,2591,2801 and a few more, and (13,q) for q=2531,2689,2797.  For larger values of 13 $\lt p \lt q \lt$ 3000, there are no nice pairs.

I am willing to believe there is a q less than 2^2^101 for which (101,q) is nice. Based on preliminary data, I doubt q would be less than 2^101.

Gerhard "These Are Rather Big Numbers" Paseman, 2019.05.31.